# Error in Matlab Function Block: Index exceeds array dimensions

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have some problem during running the code below and it give me the error
Index exceeds array dimensions. Index value 3 exceeds valid range [1-2] for array 'a'. Error in 'TEST/TEST' (line 18) if a(i)> 0
This code is the code for computing the parameter k for the scalar reference governor. and Hx and Hv are the maximal admissible output sets(MAS) with the matrices A,B,C,D hope can get some help to fix this code from your all.

```
function v = SRG_new(v_previous, r)
  A=[0 1;-275.5 -21.22];
  B=[0;1];
  C=[11.02 275.5];
  D=0;
  I=eye(2);
  Hx=(C*A); 
  Hv= C*((I-A)*((I-A)^-1)*B+D); 
  s=350; %s=max_output
  a=Hx*(r-v_previous);
  b=s-Hx-Hv*v_previous;
  k=1;
 
for i=1:100
    if a(i)> 0
        k=min(k, b(i)/a(i));
    end       
end
  k=max(k,0);
  v=v_previous + k*(r-v_previous);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this depends mainly on the size your inputs v_previous and r (As The error specifies the range "1-2" i guess, "r" and "v_previous" are scalar values).

The error occurs, because you want to iterate through 100 elements of "a", but as  `Hx=(C*A);` only creates a 1x2 Matrix, `a = Hx*(r-v_previous);` will result in a Matrix "a" with fewer than 100 entries (Exactly two entries if only multiplied with a scalar value). And this must lead to the "Out of range - Error".

To get rid of the error, simply use

```
for i=1:numel(a)
    if a(i)> 0
        k=min(k, b(i)/a(i));
    end       
end
```

This way, it will only iterate through the available array elements.

Comment: thx for helping me solve the error, the code that you suggest can work thx again for the help

Comment: I am glad I was able to help you! Then you can mark the question as solved 